# post-api calls via Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Tags: cordova, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

I'm building an app using phonegap v5.1.1. I'm having difficulties working with graph api via post method, I am using [phongap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin).

In their documentation it can be used like :

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api(String requestPath, Array permissions, Function success, Function failure)
```

but I dont know where to put method : "POST" in it.

I meant How to do this :

```
 FB.api("/{object_id}/likes",
          "POST",
            function (response) {
        });
```

and this

```
FB.api(
    "/{comment-id}",
    "POST",
    {
        "message": "This is a test comment"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

in this plugin mentioned above.
Thanks